# MinGW + GVim Compile C/C++ Failed (No such file or directory)

Tags: c++, c, mingw, vim

I need your help..

That I miss some problem with **MinGW + Gvim** Compile C/C++ on Windows Platform..

**My Development Environment :**

-> Window 7 x64 Ultimate

-> Gvim 7.4 (with Install) [C:\Program File (x86)]

-> MinGW (with Install) [D:\MinGw]

**I already Set the PATH :**

INCLUDE -> D:\MinGW\include

LIB     -> D:\MinGW\lib

PATH    -> D:\MinGW\bin;D:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin

**So My `_vimrc` set Onekey Building C++ like this:**

let s:windows_CPPFlags = 'g++\ -fexec-charset=gbk\ -Wall\ -g\ -O0\ -c\ %\ -o\ %<.o'

let s:linux_CPPFlags = 'g++\ -Wall\ -g\ -O0\ -c\ %\ -o\ %<.o'

**Some Error Pictrue , and I try Compile the cpp file in Gvim && Windows CMD :**

1: Try to Compile in Gvim . But **"No such file or directory"**

2: Try to Compile in CMD . Same Error with this Command?

CMD: g++ D:\Test Vim\hc.cpp -o D:\Test Vim\hc.exe

3: **Success for Complie in CMD** , That the **file's path should be String**!

CMD: g++ "D:\Test Vim\hc.cpp" -o "D:\Test Vim\hc.exe"

it Success! ths  file path around with " "

**So. The last Problem is that:
How do I write correct in** `_vimrc` ??

Some picture:
[Error Picture](http://www.zhihu.com/question/26806532)

Comment: Just not use spaces in output folder name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use c.vim plugin to build C++ source file with Ctrl+F9 
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213

Comment: Thanks. I solve this problem with c.vim . Maybe the file path folder name with space...